# Direction of current in a LR circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, kirchhoffs-laws

Assume the easiest circuit with a voltage source U(t), a inductor L and a resistor R in series. The voltage source is function of time.

We can have a differential equation:
$$U=I'L+IR$$

But the thing is, we don't really know the direction of the derivative of I, then it can also be

$$U=-I'L+IR$$

But this two equations have different solutions (at least the homogenous part because the characteristic values are different)

So which one is correct?

It seems that when I do tasks I always just assume I' has the same sign as I. But actually this is not true?

Comment: The 1st is always true regardless of Polarity or shape of I(t)

Comment: Assume a positive direction for the current; the analysis will sort out the sign.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that when I do tasks I always just assume I' has the same sign as I. But actually this is not true?

If you consider a sinusoidal stimulus, it will only be true for half the cycle.

But you should still use

$$ U = I'L + IR $$

because when the signs of \$I'\$ and \$I\$ are opposite, they will have opposite effect on the potential difference across the part, just as the equation says.